# Implementing an Excel-like formula engine

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, vba

I am looking for a professional tool that will enable me to implement an excel like formula engine.

I require support for custom functions, an editor (in winforms or WPF) which gives a descent user experience (Intellisense , auto complete, partial evaluation of the formula etc...)

All I could find so far are just back-end projects such as:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17853/Implementing-an-Excel-like-formula-engine

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57264/Eval3-wrapper

And those do not provide any client side , only backend engine.

Comment: Check out [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/)

Comment: I don't think this is a classic case of "what is the best tool for .NET that does XYZ?" question. I have done a lot of research and failed to find a tool with both function evaluation capabilites (incluing custom functions support) and UI capabilites. So the answers here might be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some Excel-formula-engines out there (mostly commercial) - but since you need a frontend too the only one I know of is [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/). Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

[Spreadsheetgear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/?aw=spreadsheetgear) is one of the more established products. According to their site Microsoft also use their product?? It's expensive though.